# What is Prester Omega?

Tags: marvel

In *Defenders Vol 4*, Strange and the Other find the Concordance Engine, and it was guarded by Prester Omega, who is extremely powerful.

So who exactly is Prester Omega?

Is he from the Marvel-616 world? And if not, then why is he in the 616 reality?

According to the [Marvel Wiki page for the Concordance Engine](http://marvel.wikia.com/Concordance_Engine):

> It is the heart and soul of a universe, the map of everything, and if it would be destroyed it will lead to the destruction of the universe.

So has the Concordance Engine existed since the beginning of the universe, or did somebody create it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Prester Omega is one of a group of humans and superhumans chosen to guard the Concordance Engines; devices created by the Celestials of another universe, capable of altering reality and suspected of being lynchpins to all of reality.

- Prester Omega's abilities are unknown, potentially given to him by the Concordance in order to affect it's protection. His abilities allow him to move at superhuman speeds, dispel beings as powerful as the Worthy, Nul and able to disrupt metahuman abilities such as Iron Fist's chi manifestation.
- As far as to the creators of the Concordance Engines:

> - The machines were built by a group of superhumans called the Presters from an alternate universe where the Celestials had become cosmically suicidal. These "Death Celestials" destroyed their universe and then others. The Presters had escaped and observed the sporadic things in the other universes which had temporarily held back the Death Celestials, and then used the Concordance Engines to recreate those elements on Earth-616. Their intention is to make that Earth into an armory or redoubt against this ultimate cosmic menace.

#### Greater Detail

---

**Fantastic Four Vol. 1, Issue 54 (1966) introduces us to Prester John, monarch of Pentoxere, a kingdom in eastern Asia. Supposedly the descendant of one of the Three Kings, Gaspar, Melchior or Balthasar.**

[image]

- This former monarch is found by Wyatt Wingfoot and the Human Torch in a Survival Chair, a relic technology allowing Prester John to live for at least 700 years as the guardian of **[the Evil Eye](http://marvel.wikia.com/Evil_Eye)**.
- The Evil Eye was a powerful weapon/technology/MacGuffin from the early years of the Marvel Universe - I read these stories as a kid and the Evil Eye Saga was one of my most favorite of the time period.

> - From Wikipedia: Prester John is a centuries-old explorer who was born in an unnamed kingdom in Eastern Asia, which he once ruled. He was an ally of King Richard the Lionhearted and served in his court. He is the possessor of the Evil Eye, a mystic object of power which was bestowed upon him in the extra-dimensional land of Avalon, and which can project vast amounts of energy. He has been a priest, a king, an adventurer, a traveler, and explorer.
> - Prester John was preserved from the 12th century until modern times in the Chair of Survival by the alchemists of Avalon. When he awoke, he met the Human Torch and Wyatt Wingfoot, and witnessed the seeming destruction of the Evil Eye. Prester John later became temporarily possessed by an alien power-stone, and battled the Thing and Iron Man.

**Note Prester Omega sitting by the representation of the Concordance Engine. I say representation because the device is supposedly THE UNIVERSE or a facsimile, that if destroyed could destroy part or all of the Earth-616 universe.**

[image]

- Prester Omega's slumped over appearance is reminiscent of the appearance of Prester John's very first appearance in Fantastic Four all those years ago.
- Now add to this idea the the Concordance Engine is capable of wish fulfillment, bridging realities and altering reality as it sees fit, creating matter and energy at will.
- The Concordance Engine appeared to give Prester Omega the ability to destroy or displace Nul, one of the Worthy. Prester Omega stopped Nul with almost no effort. Which isn't surprising if you can alter reality.

**Prester John claims there is a relationship between he and Prester Omega as "brother knights" protecting other artifacts of power. If so, the relationship between the two characters has not yet been fully explained or explored. It is likely part of the secret history of the world that has been hidden by the Concordance Engine(s) to protect itself/themselves from misuse.**

- Dr. Strange theorizes that Prester John's Concordance had possibly been destroyed or lost in the distant past and this may have been why Prester John had gone mad. Prester Omega theorized this as well. See black-captioned thoughts of Prester Omega below:

[image]

*The object you see pressed against the Silver Surfer's neck is the stellar staff of Prester John, which now has the Evil Eye incorporated into it. It is capable of harming even the likes of the Silver Surfer. (Defenders #3, 2011)*

- The Omega symbols now conveniently placed in all of the Prester's hands has been seen before, as well. In the hands of a little known character from the 1970's: Omega, the Unknown, an artificial lifeform from another world. What his relationship to the Prester's and their mission is as yet unknown.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

Marvel's own site does not have a listing for Prester Omega, but the Marvel Wiki [does](http://marvel.wikia.com/Prester_Omega_(Earth-616)), and it notes that he *is* from Earth-616.

They explain:

> He is the guard of the Concordance Engine located under Wundagore Mountain. Prester John lured Nul to the Engine, hoping the Breaker of Worlds could destroy it and thus allow him to escape to another world. Instead, Omega destroyed Nul, and the Defenders took the Engine and Omega back to Doctor Strange's home.

Looking at his [list of appearances](http://marvel.wikia.com/Category:Prester_Omega_(Earth-616)/Appearances), he appears to be a fairly recently created character (his first appearance seems to be in 2012 or so).

Comment: Not entirely recent. Under the name of Prester John (more closed based off of the mythological character), the Wikipedia article has him showing up further back. Assuming, of course, it's the same guy... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prester_John_(comics)

Comment: but it doesn't say what it is only a guard but it is human or alien or cosmic entity because he kills nul like it was nothing

Comment: @SeanDuggan, Prester John is an existing marvel character based on the mythological character from the 60's and is not Prester Omega.  However there does seem to be a connection between the character.  

Fun fact, there is evidence that the rumored christian king in Asia that was fighting the Muslims in 3th century may have been European Christians misinterpreting news of Genghis Khan's expansion into Khwarezmian Empire which saw the leveling of Baghdad and the death of 3/4ths of the population of the Iranian Plateau.